# How to calculate progress of AsyncTask which downloads multiple files

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I'm trying to download a few png files using various for loops. May I ask how exactly do I employ the  publishProgress() method in my case?

Here are my codes:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


    for(PlaceDetails place : places){
        for(int v = 14; v <=16; v++){   
            for (int y = 0; y <= placeBottomLeft.getYTile(); y++){
                for(int x = placeTopLeft.getXTile(); x <= placeBottomRight.getXTile(); x++){
                    try {
                        //Download some stuff here
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    for (int w = zoom -1 ; w <= zoom+1; w++){
        for (int y = topLeft.getYTile(); y <= bottomLeft.getYTile(); y++){
            for(int x = topLeft.getXTile(); x <= bottomRight.getXTile(); x++){
                try {
                    //Download some stuff here again
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("URL::: ERROR", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to download stuff in 2 separate for loops in the doInBackground  method. However most of the examples I've seen just make the thread sleep and use the for loop counter number as the integer for the publishProgress() method. How should I be using it in this case? Thanks!

EDITED:

To further clarify, I would like to know if it's possible to have the progress update to include things done in the onPostExecuteMethod().

```
protected void onPostExecute (String result){
    File newFileDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Qiito Offline/offlineMap");
    File fileDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() 
            + "/test");
    try {
        Log.e("Starting :: ", newFileDir.getPath());
        File newFile = new File(newFileDir, "" + tID + ".zip");
        newFileDir.mkdirs();
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
        ZipOutputStream zipoutput = new ZipOutputStream(output);
        zip(fileDir, fileDir, zipoutput);
        zipoutput.close();
        output.close();
        deleteDirectory(fileDir);
        mNotificationHelper.completed(); //method I used for my NotificationHelper to inform that the entire process is completed
    } catch (IOException excep) {
        Log.e("ERROR!!" , excep.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

In postExecute(), I am trying to zip up the png files in another folder, and subsequently deleting all the png files. Is the progress bar able to include this as well? Otherwise I'll just make do with the tracking of downloading the png files.

Comment: Do you want to show the progress for all the files together or a progress for different files separately.?

Comment: If possible I would like to show the progress of it starting from onPreExecute() all the way until it is completed at onPostExecute().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this code in `doInBackground()`:

```
int totalCount  = 0; // total images count
int counter = 0; // current downloaded files count

// images - ArrayList with images
totalCount = images.size();

// download and publish progress
   int imagesCount = images.size(); 
   for (int i = 0; i < imagesCount; i++) {
            // download image

            publishProgress((int) ((counter++ / (float) totalCount) * 100));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this! The problem is, the number of images is dynamic, and thus I would not be to tell. The counters for each for loop is not a fixed number...

Comment: Can u calculate all images count before loops?

Comment: I guess it might be possible but I was thinking if there's a better way, as calculating before hand would require going through all the loops twice and I'm not sure if it will slow down the entire process. I've also updated my question on wondering if it's possible to calculate the PostExecute process as well, does it complicate matters?

Comment: Or u can just post steps count as progress: e.g. loops count, and after each loop update progress by calculated number of %.

Comment: After downloading images, u can start another AsyncTask, which will zip and delete png files, and there u can show progress easily, because you can get downloaded images count

Comment: ok I will try that thank you! So there's no way to include onPostExecute() tasks together in the calculation? Having another AsyncTask would mean I have 2 progress bars...?

Comment: "include tasks"??? You can start another AsyncTask in onPostExecute, you will know exactly, that images were downloaded successfully and they are ready for zipping

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21714/discussion-between-lyk-and-veaceslav-gaidarji)